# How to print out an element which has been processed by an function.

Tags: java

Good day everyone, I'm finishing some studycode and I'm stuck at the last step! 
That is, to print out an element from an array which has been randomly generated by calling upon a function which does so.
I'm scratching my head here, since the statement must pick out a certain element from the array and then print it out, and I've run it through an visualizer and it does everything correct right up to the end. 
So I'm hoping if you guys(and gals) can help me understand a bit better what's going on.

```
public class randomfylki
{
public static int veljaEitt(int [] a)
{
 int x = (int)(Math.random()*10);


 return a[x];

}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  int a[] = new int[10];
    int i;
  for( i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {

  a[i] = (int)(Math.random()*100);



  }
veljaEitt(a);
System.out.print(a);
}

}
```

I do hope you'll forgive me for having a bad title, I'm not quite sure on what it should be ._.

Comment: System.out.println(veljaEitt(a));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
    veljaEitt(a);
System.out.print(a);
```

do this

```
System.out.print(veljaEitt(a));
```

Comment: Oh my goodness gracious. It was that simple? I feel like a fool :'(

Comment: @Josef.. yes it is ... actually you need to print the return value of the method... welcome to the stackoverflow, if you think any answer is helpful you can upvote/accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your method returns an `int`, you can store that into a variable and print the variable:

```
int result = veljaEitt(a);
System.out.print(result);
```